# How to display HTML tags in Blockquotes

Tags: support, design, blockquote

How would you include HTML tags as part of the blockquotes when you would like to signify these tags as quoted text instead of code?

Code:

```
<url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>
```

BlockQuote: (notice that the URL is interpreted as a valid HTML tag and hence is not a part of the text of the blockquote)

> http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could html encode them yourself:

```
 &lt;url&gt;http://www.website.com/order/index.asp&lt;/url&gt;
```

yields:

> <url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp</url&gt;